# Find the solutions for $2y^2dx-(x+y)^2dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find all the solutions for the equations: $$
> 2y^2dx - (x+y)^2dy = 0
> $$

---

Now I thought that I can use substitution:

$$
2(\frac{y}{x})^2dx - (1+\frac{y}{x}+(\frac{y}{x})^2)dy = 0
$$

Now lets take:

$$
\frac{y}{x} = v \Rightarrow y = xv \Rightarrow y’ = v + xv’
$$

Our equation becomes:

$$
2v^2-(1+v+v^2)(v+xv’) = 0
$$

Getting:

$$
2v^2 - (v+v^2+v^3+xv’+xvv’+xv^2v’) = 0
$$

Therefore:

$$
v^3-v^2+v+(x+xv+xv^2)v’ = 0
$$

Here I’m not sure what to do next.

Thanks.

Comment: You have missed a factor of $2$ in the first line of your solution it should be $2\frac{y}{x}$ instead of $\frac{y}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

This ODE is Homogeneous:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2y^2}{(x+y)^2}$$
Let $y=vx \implies y'=v+xv'$, then
$$x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{2v^2}{(1+v)^2}-v=-\frac{v(1+v^2)}{(1+v)^2}$$
$$\implies \int \frac{(1+v)^2}{v(1+v^2)} dv=-\int \frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\int \left(\frac{1}{v}+\frac{2}{1+v^2}\right) dv= -\ln C x$$
$$\implies \ln v +2 \tan^{-1}v=-\ln Cx$$
$$\implies 2\tan^{-1} (y/x)=-\ln (Cy).$$

Comment: please check out my solution its a bit simpler(i think)

Comment: where? could you elaborate more please as far as i can see i have no term $\frac{y}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

let $\frac{x}{y}=v$
or

$\frac{dx}{dy}=v+y\frac{dv}{dy}$

thus your differential equation can be rewritten as

$$2\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{{(x+y)}^2}{y^2}$$

$$2\frac{dx}{dy}={(1+v)}^2$$

$$2v+2y\frac{dv}{dy}={(1+v)}^2$$

$$\frac{dv}{v^2+1}=\frac{dy}{2y}$$
$$2\tan^{-1} v= \ln A y \implies 2 \tan^{-1} (x/y)=\ln Ay \implies 2(\pi/2-\tan^{-1} (y/x)) =\ln Ay $$ $$\implies  2\tan^{-1} (y/x)=\pi-\ln Ay \implies 2 \tan^{-1}(y/x)=-\ln By$$
Here, we have used $$\tan^{-1}z+\tan^{-1}(1/z)=\pi/2$$

Comment: you may see your solution now I have edited it.

Comment: @Z.Ahmed yes thank you